# Ubuntu freezes after login(tried methods suggested)

Tags: system-installation, freeze

I tried to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 10. The installation went well. After restarting my PC, Ubuntu just freezes after I log in.

I've tried methods suggested by others including spamming <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> to try to get into recovery mode but I get this:

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.   

grub>_
```

The screen is frozen like this:

[image: frozen desktop]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you still move the mouse cursor when the graphical session freezes like that? Can you still switch to a virtual console with Ctrl+Alt+F2? If so, please log in there and [edit] your question to [share some log files](/a/440088/175814) with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented first but I'm not allowed, due to lack of reputation.

Please don't log in. When you get the prompt, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You should then see the terminal, where you can log in. If the login works there, you can start debugging.

I would start and check if you have disk space left:

```
df -h
```

A full home partition is often the reason for a frozen UI. But this is just one possibility. Please poke around a little bit, so you can start asking more specific questions.

Good luck :)

Comment: My home partition has 500gigs free. So that's not an issue